# Channeling two named PIPEs with a GNU Radio flowgraph | String transmitted on one end does not reach the other end

Tags: gnuradio

**1)**
I created two named PIPEs:

```
$ mkfifo pipe_in
$ mkfifo pipe_out
```

**2)**
Then connected `pipe_in` to `pipe_out` with the following GNU radio flowgraph:

[image]

File Source config:

- Repeat: `No`
- Vec Length: `1` (default setting)
- Add begin tag: `pmt.PMT_NIL` (default setting)

File Sink config:

- Unbuffered: `Off`
- Vec Length: `1` (default setting)
- Append file: `Overwrite`

**3)**
Finaly, I start running the flowgraph, then write a string to `pipe_in` hoping to see it reach `pipe_out` by running the following two commands in separate terminals:

```
TERM2 $ tail -f pipe_out
```

and

```
TERM1 $ echo 'hello world!' > pipe_in
```

Unfortunately the string never reaches pipe_out. Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: Can you upload a higher resolution image?

Comment: @rmagno, unfortunately that is currently not possible, afaik. It's a GNU Radio limitation...

Comment: @rmagno are you and OP related? Yep, on GNU Radio 3.7, the GNU Radio Companion tool has a fixed rendering size, i.e. can't zoom (the picture would still be easier to read if it *wasn't* scaled up, but that's a different story)

Comment: @Marcus, is there a more recent version of GNU Radio that does not use a fixed rendering size? I am genuinely interested.

Comment: @gmagno yep! The current development version on git does exactly that. Also, Qt5 instead of Qt4 for visualization widgets, and Py3 instead of Python2 (optional), better build system, you know, stuff like that :)

Comment: this might be a bit off-topic here, because it's more about using FIFOs / pipes than about signal processing. Have you read `man 7 pipe`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: why're you asking?

Comment: @rmagno an rmagno answering to an fmagno, I just liked that :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if I replace the GNU Radio part with: `tail -f pipe_in > pipe_out` it all works. So, I don't think you are accurate when you say this is more about FIFOs/pipes. GNU Radio has something to do with this issue as well. GNU Radio is usually a topic discussed on signal processing afaik.

Comment: I think I'm close to the answer. In fact, `tail -f pipe_in > pipe_out` will only transfer the information if I kill the process. It seems that the data is being buffered and gets flushed right before killing the process. This also works with GNU Radio but I must set the `File Sink` Unbuffered setting to `On`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how tail works, it waits until the end to print the last n lines. If you use `cat` instead, it should work.

I hope it helps.